# Выборочная очистка выводов с экрана

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Есть ли способ очистки некоторых выводов в терминале?
Пример:

```
print(1)
print(2)
# Удаляем вывод print(1) из терминала
# Но оставляем вывод print(2)
```

Comment: Нету. Смотрите в сторону curses.

Comment: Есть... Но с огромными платформозависимыми (и терминалозависимыми) ограничениями. Поэтому лучше сразу смотреть в сторону популярных библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

Способ есть. Вопрос в другом: а вам это нужно? Это лишняя работа. Существуют готовые решения таких задач. Вывод можно очень хорошо организовать с curses.

---

Наперво необходимо перенести каретку на начало первого вывода `print("1")`. Способов много. К примеру можно воспользоваться ctypes и напрямую сделать это. Код я вспомнить не смогу, но точно знаю о возможности онного. Или же обернуть стандартный вывод выводом colorama, который предоставляет обработчик ANSI escape последовательностей, с помощью которых можно так же перевести каретку на нужную позицию. После этого можно затереть первый вывод пустыми символами `print(' ' * len(message))#, где message = "1".` и вернуть каретку в исходное положение. Повторюсь: а вам оно надо? Колесо уже изобретено и оно удобнее овала.

Comment: У меня сервак постоянно пингует и проверяет наличие интернета, и при запуске кода в консоле появляется карточка кода, и постоянно её принтовать при очистке - нет никакого желания